# How to prove $\mathop{\rm Var}[X] \geq 0$ with Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality??

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

$\def\Var{\mathop{\rm Var}} \def\E{{\mathrm E}\,} $
X is non-negative r.v.
Since, $\Var[X]$ is a sum of square so I knew that $$\Var[X] \geq 0$$

I have to prove that $\Var[X] \geq 0$ by using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.
I did prove this $$\E[XY]^2 \leq \mathrm \E[X^2] \E[Y^2]$$ by quadratic equation.
But, I still have no idea on proving this problem.

I did try to multiple $\frac{(1^2+1^2+...+1^2)}{n}$ on the $\Var[X] = \E[(X-\E[X])^2$
However, I realize that in the Cauchy-Schwarz, it also need $a_i = cb_i$ to make it true. So, I could not assume this.

I also tried to read on wikipedia about this inequality 
but there is nothing about this step.

May anyone guide me anything to start with?

Comment: It is not hard to show that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. The fact that this is $\ge 0$ is straight C-S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to show that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. The fact that this is $\ge 0$ is straight C-S.

**Remark:** Of course we do not need C-S to show that variance is non-negative. But we can use it to prove the more general $E(XY)\le (E(X^2)E(Y^2))^{1/2}$.

To prove the useful fact that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$, expand $(X-\mu)^2$ and use the linearity of expectation. We get $E(X^2)-2\mu E(X)+\mu^2$, which is $E(X^2)-\mu^2$.

We really do not need to use the alternate formula for variance, though I did want to mention it. We can use C-S to show that $E(W^2) \ge (E(W))^2$, with $W=X-\mu$.

Comment: I still could not see it yet. I think all I have to do is proving $E[X^2] > E[X]^2$ but I'm struggling on this for many hours.

Comment: C-S may be more familiar in the form I mention in the remark, with $X$ **and** $Y$. Now put $Y=1$.

Comment: I did try that too but I thought that this inequality holds true only when $X=tY$ which means that if I gave $Y = 1$ I will get $X = t$ only.

Comment: @ZealChaiwut: You may be remembering C-S not quite accurately. It says that we have **equality** only in the case $X=tY$ for some constant $t$.

Comment: I see the point where I missed now..... Thank you a lot for replying me.

Answer (score 2):

Its just that $Var(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)$ which are $(X-E(X))^2$non-negative random variables. Expectation of non-negative random variables is non-negative.

Comment: I understand your point but in the question I have to use this C-S inequality to prove it.